# Is the limit superior defined on every real-valued function with a finite range?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I know the limit superior isn't always defined on function in general, but intuitively, I don't see how it could be undefined on a function with a finite range. However, I didn't find any sources discussing this.

Comment: I know I could just edit your question, but it's important to tell you this: it's not *limit* superior, it's *limes* superior.

Comment: @5xum Are you sure about that? When I [google it](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22limes%20superior%22&oq=%22limes%20superior%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1315j0j7), I get "limit superior" for the English pages. I think "limes superior" is German.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I had no idea the entire english speaking word is using the wrong expression. And yes, I feel it is wrong. Because $\limsup$ us the "largest wall", and limes is wall in latin...